# Replace the dataframe entries with binary value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Trying to replace certain strings with a binary value. I tried to find and replace but it only works for one value. I'd like to do it for multiple different labels.
I'd like to replace dog and bat with 1 and cat and snail with 0 :

```
animal 
0 cat 
1 dog
2 snail
3 bat
4 deer
```

To:

```
  animal 
0 0
1 1
2 0
3 1
4 0
```

Here is my sample code:

```
cold=['cat','snail','deer']
df['animal'] = np.where(df['animal']=cold, '0', '1')
```

Comment: `df['animal'].isin(cold).astype(int)`.

Comment: @QuangHoang, mate you can post your answer. I will upvote you. This one makes the trick.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I run the answer provided, I do not get the intended results. Cold variable is [cat,snail,deer]. All the numbers go to 0, however I want the ones that match the case to be 1 and the others that do not match the case to be 0.

Comment: Are you sure the answers are not working? Perhaps you have other details you have not put in your question?

Comment: I am unsure on what I would be missing when I perform this code, all of my entries end up as 0s. Is there another alternative to this solution?

Comment: You have to be careful as you are assigning the result back to the same column, so what you request should only be performed once. If you are performing the codes on the resulted dataframe again, it will surely not return the answer

Comment: Thank you! I think that may have been the issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code almost works, just need a slight change.

```
df['animal'] = np.where(df['animal'].isin(cold), '0', '1')

  animal
0      0
1      1
2      0
3      1
4      0
```

Or you could use the answer in the comment.

```
df['animal'] = (~df['animal'].isin(cold)).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

I Like np.select the most:

```
import numpy as np

cold = ['cat','snail','deer']


df = (df
 .assign(animal=lambda x: np.select([x.animal.isin(cold)],
                                    [0], default=1)
        )
)
```